# Kubuntu 20.04.1 fails to boot after dist-upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, kubuntu, shared-library

I've decided to install Kubuntu 20.04.1 from [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/20.04.1/release/kubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso). During the installation I checked:

- "Minimal installation";
- "Download updates while installing Kubuntu";
- "Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats".

The installation was smooth and the system made quite nice first impression. But then I've experienced a very strange error as a consequence of simply executing dist-upgrade. Running

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade --yes
```

(as root) and rebooting afterwards yields a broken system. More precisely, the system fails to load and I'm greeted by ash/busybox and the following error:

```
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: error while loading shared libraries: liblzma.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules: ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=ee274d63-783d-4ebf-a1b6-d499643bd924 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!
```

During the dist-upgrade, a more recent kernel version is installed - it gets updated from 5.4.0-52 to 5.4.0-58 (and the ISO itself contains 5.4.0-42 kernel). However after the dist-upgrade and reboot switching these kernels using GRUB leads to the same error from above.

I can consistently replicate this behavior both in the VirtualBox guest and on a real Dell Latitude 5490 by reinstalling Kubuntu from scratch and executing the command.

Am I misunderstanding something? Should I just open a new issue on Kubuntu's bugtracker? Any advice/explanation would be greatly appreciated as this is a very frustrating situation because even Arch wasn't *that* fragile.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to sidestep this problem by manually executing

```
update-initramfs -u
```

after dist-upgrade.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I've found the hidden variable. Each time `update-initramfs` was called automatically after new kernel installation, I had an external filesystem mounted somewhere (for irrelevant reasons). This filesystem happened to contain `liblzma.so.5` of it's own. Using `lsinitramfs | grep lzma` I managed to spot that automatically generated initrd actually contained the missing library, but it was copied to the path mirroring the path of the library from the mount. I.e. instead of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5` initrd contains `/mnt/test/liblzma.so.5`. I tried to mount the external filesystem to other locations (e.g. `/root/mnt`, `/media/root/mnt`) but yet to find the place where it won't break initrd generation.

For the time being I just unmount the external filesystem before manually regenerating initrd. I have no idea why `update-initramfs` is behaving this way and if it is an intended behavior so any clarification are still highly welcome.